# How do I fix this post request error 405 'Method not allowed'?

Tags: java, post

I'm newbie in java learning my way through get and post requests in java can someone please take a look at my code and help me understand why it isn't working when I am trying to upload a file to a web url via post request?

Extra info:
file to the mentioned url could be uploaded via curl -T filename.extention url

Here's the code

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Init Binary");
        URLConnection urlconnection = null;
        try {
            File file = new File(args[0]);
            URL url = new URL("https://transfer.sh/");
            urlconnection = url.openConnection();
            urlconnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlconnection.setDoInput(true);

            if (urlconnection instanceof HttpURLConnection) {
                ((HttpURLConnection) urlconnection).setRequestMethod("PUT");
                ((HttpURLConnection) urlconnection).setRequestProperty("Content-type", "text/plain");
                ((HttpURLConnection) urlconnection).connect();
            }

            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(urlconnection.getOutputStream());
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            int i;
            // read byte by byte until end of stream
            while ((i = bis.read()) > 0) {
                bos.write(i);
            }
            bis.close();
            bos.close();
            System.out.println(((HttpURLConnection) urlconnection).getResponseMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {

            InputStream inputStream;
            int responseCode = ((HttpURLConnection) urlconnection).getResponseCode();
            if ((responseCode >= 200) && (responseCode <= 202)) {
                inputStream = ((HttpURLConnection) urlconnection).getInputStream();
                int j;
                while ((j = inputStream.read()) > 0) {
                    System.out.println(j);
                }

            } else {
                inputStream = ((HttpURLConnection) urlconnection).getErrorStream();
            }
            ((HttpURLConnection) urlconnection).disconnect();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Expected output should be the file url that's uploaded, which is received as the response.

Comment: and which method call gives you that? maybe you need to provide a class that provides an implementation for that method

Comment: Maybe try `POST` instead of `PUT`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the prompt responses 'POST' and 'PUT' both doesn't seem to work, @Stultuske I'll be glad f you can link me to sample code or some documentation meanwhile with POST request I get _Internal Server Error_